# Spring batch job configuration with dependent steps that needs to do a complex process

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, jobs

I have requirement which is similar to the below case. I am new to spring batch so can someone guide me in creating a job for this case.

> 1. Read the list of countries in chunks(say i need to read 5 countries at a time)
> 2. For each country get the list of states
> 3. For each state get the list of cities
> 4. a. For each city get the list of people in chunks(say i need to read 1000 records at a time) 
>       b. Process the people information 
>       c. Write the information into the DB

All the above steps are dependent say i need to pass the country id from step 1 to step 2, the stateId from step 2 to step 3 and the cityId from step 3 to step 4.

The internal execution of the steps 1 and 4 can be parallel. Even this can be done on different jvm

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few options. First, I'd suggest looking at the `org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor` and chaining these processes in one step (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors).

Another option would be to use a promotion listener to share data between steps (`org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener`). This would allow you to create different steps, and control the commit interval in each step. Here's an example of basic XML config for a promotion listener:

```
<bean id="promotionListener" class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <property name="keys">
        <util:list>
            <value>countries</value>
            <value>states</value>
            <value>cities</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can add parameters to the `ExecutionContext` via custom `Tasklet` by implementing the interface and overriding the `execute` method. In the example above, three lists are being added to the promotion listener, which can then be shared amongst steps down the chain.

Here's a quick example of how to override the `execute` method:

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    ExecutionContext executionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext();

    executionContext.put("countries", /* country list */;
    executionContext.put("states", /* state list */);
    executionContext.put("cities", /* city list */);

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

You'd probably want to break this out into three different tasklets - one for each step in your process - and add one list per tasklet. I'd also beef up the `RepeatStatus` handling in case of an error, but it's just a quick example to give you an idea.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time. I doesn't want to chain these process into a single step as that may be a time consuming. I want each and every step to be parallel. Yes i was trying based on the second choice you mentioned but I am unable to get some samples for chained process like this.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand you. The first example shows how to add content to the execution context via custom tasklet implementation. This is different than chaining processes via CompositeItemProcessor. In your comment, you said: `... I am unable to get some samples for chained process like this...` Are you looking for examples of chaining processes, or more info on adding content to the execution context?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the suggested approach since your step# 1 to step#4 are basically **reading from database** even though those four steps look separate steps but those four steps are a single step. And you should reduce DB hits too in addition to solving the problem functionally.

You can use Spring Batch partitioning approach where you partition your data by triple - **(Country, State, City)** then your reader reads data in chunks of 1000 for each triple in parallel threads i.e. `WHERE COUNTRY = ? AND STATE =? AND CITY = ?`.

You have to implement [Partitioner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#stepExecutionSplitter) interface and create your triplets by running a `SELECT` query and doing `GROUP BY COUNTRY,STATE,CITY`.

Then you write a simple reader which returns a `JdbcPagingItemReader` and you use  `COUNTRY,STATE,CITY` values populated in `Partitioner` in `WHERE` clause of `PagingQueryProvider`.

You will have to inject partition values from partitioner logic to reader by using syntax `@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[...]}"`.

```
org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner
```

You will not be required to run all partitions in one go - you can control number of parallel threads by providing a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to partition master step and setting its `concurrencyLimit` to appropriate value.

Then you go on and write your processor and writer. You will have to mark a step & step components in `@StepScope` if injecting values from partition logic.

Here is [Sample of partitiong](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/) but its xml based configuration. I prefer Java based config.

Hope it helps !!